# Nearest neighbor distance for k=1 in units of time

Tags: python, pandas, datediff, nearest-neighbor, date-difference

I have the following dataframe

```
A_key      Date
      A1      2016-05-03
      A1      2016-09-25
      A2      2015-02-25
      A2      2015-02-25
      A3      2015-10-04
      A3      2016-03-15
      A3      2016-04-10
      A4      2015-09-26
      A4      2015-09-26
```

I want to obtain the nearest neighbor distance for each distinct A_key in units of days for n_neighbor(k) = 1 such that the output looks like the following

```
      A_key      Date       Distance
      A1      2016-05-03     145
      A1      2016-09-25     145
      A2      2015-02-25     0
      A2      2015-02-25     0
      A3      2015-10-04     163
      A3      2016-03-15     26
      A3      2016-04-10     26
      A4      2015-09-26     0
      A4      2015-09-26     0
```

Comment: mmm why is the second A3 not 163? What criteria do you use for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This base up on the `groupby` to split your original df into small unique key dataframe , then we using `numpy` broadcast to speed up the whole calculation

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
l=[]
for _, x in df.groupby('A_key'):
    s=np.abs((x['Date'].values - x['Date'].values[:,None])).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)
    s[[np.arange(len(s))] * 2]=9999
    l.append(np.min(s,1))

df['New']=np.concatenate(l)
df
Out[501]: 
  A_key       Date  New
0    A1 2016-05-03  145
1    A1 2016-09-25  145
2    A2 2015-02-25    0
3    A2 2015-02-25    0
4    A3 2015-10-04  163
5    A3 2016-03-15   26
6    A3 2016-04-10   26
7    A4 2015-09-26    0
8    A4 2015-09-26    0
```

Comment: Why is the second A3 26 instead of 163? I mean its the same as OPs ouput, just dont get why it is so

Comment: @yatu min of diff among all the Dates different

Comment: @yatu, its not as straight-forward as groupby and diff. The OP wants the nearest point from each point in a group

Comment: Ah, get now the idea of `nearest`, got it. Thanks

Comment: @W-B, Great use of array reshaping

Comment: Just a small warning concerning this code, take the first row of A3 and move it to the end of the DataFrame, then run the method , you'll see that the result is wrong. In order to don't have any surprise by using this code you have to sort by A_key first and don't care about your current index (because the resulting ordering will be based depending on which group the groupby method takes)

Comment: @abcdaire sort it before doing my method

Comment: Yes, but even if you sort , if your original index is meaningful for you, it will be lost, I just want to warn about that :) But nice method !

Comment: @abcdaire this can be solved, save original index as  idx, then sort_values with A_Key, then doing what I doing above , then reindex with idx for the output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dates to Epoch using this code:

```
import time
date_time = '2016-05-03 00:00:00'
pattern = '%Y-%m-`enter code here`%d %H:%M:%S'
epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))
```

Then, simply subtract the value from its neighbor value. Note, the result is going to be in milliseconds, so you will have to divide by (1000*60*60*24) to convert it to days.

Answer (score 0):

You have already sorted by date in each key.
So all you need is compute the distance to the next and previous date in the same key.
I tried this (in Swift) to compute distance between 2 dates as formatted as 2015-05-22

```
func dist(_ d1: String, _ d2: String) -> Int {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    if let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: d1), let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: d2) {
        let distance = date1.timeIntervalSince(date2) / 86400
        return abs(Int(distance))
    } else { return 0 }
}

print(dist("2015-05-25", "2015-05-22"))
```

You can now loop through the values in one key to compute the minimum distance for a given key (except itself of course)

Comment: Thanks, but its not just distance between consecutive dates, for a given A_key if there are three records, for each record compute its distance in time with the other two and pick the minimum which represents the nearest neighbor distance

Comment: Right, unless the array is already ordered ; then need to compare with previous and next dates (if exist) only ; all others will be further than this one ; and as abcdaire is looking for the closest…

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a possible solution using only Pandas

Let's give the current index a name (for convenience and be sure that we recover everything well)

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.index.name = 'id'
```

We are first going to sort by date and apply a function to each group,
it is important to note that we are going to rely on the fact that pandas preserve the row order inside a group (see documentation)

```
sorted_df = sorted_df = df.sort_values('Date')
result_df = sorted_df.groupby('A_key').apply(nearest_date_distance)
```

So now let see what we have inside the `nearest_date_distance` function
The function relies on the fact that the Date will be sorted , therefore we compute the time to the date before and the time to the date after, the difference between the current day and the next day is negative that's why we add the `.abs()`.Finally we take the minimum between these two distances (btw the min operator won't take the missing value (NaT) that you have for the first row of time_to_before and last row of time to after)

```
def nearest_date_distance(sub):
    time_to_before = sub['Date'].diff()
    time_to_after = sub['Date'].diff(-1).abs()
    nearest_date_distance = pd.concat([time_to_before, time_to_after],axis=1).min(axis=1)
    nearest_date_distance.name = 'Distance'
    return nearest_date_distance
```

Finally I lied a bit `result_df` will be a MultiIndex Serie (not a dataframe) of this form:

```
A_key  id
A1     0    145 days
       1    145 days
A2     2      0 days
       3      0 days
A3     4    163 days
       5     26 days
       6     26 days
A4     7      0 days
       8      0 days
```

We can easily convert it to a DataFrame and having a proper naming for our original index helps to see that everything is indexed the same as in the original df.

```
result_df =sorted_df.groupby('A_key').apply(nearest_date_distance).reset_index(level=0)

    A_key   Distance
id      
0   A1  145 days
1   A1  145 days
2   A2  0 days
3   A2  0 days
4   A3  163 days
5   A3  26 days
6   A3  26 days
7   A4  0 days
8   A4  0 days
```

and if you need the Date on the resulting Dataframe `result_df['Date'] = df['Date']`should do the trick :)